# Correlation between two random signals changes each time it is calculated

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, correlation

I have two signals in MATLAB, say

```
a = randn(1,1e6);
b = randn(1,1e6);
```

I am finding the correlation between them as follows:

```
R=corrcoef(a,b);
r = R(2,1);
```

Now each time I run my code, the correlation coefficient is different. I even tried to increase the number of samples (from `1e6` to higher values) but that didn't work. Is there some other way to find the correlation coefficient between such signals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are confusing *sample* correlation coefficient with *theoretical* correlation coefficient. The former is a *random* value resulting from the (ramdom) signals *generated in the simulation*; the latter is a *number* which is computed *from the statistical model* of the signal generation process.

What you are computing in your code is the *sample* correlation coefficient, which depends on the actual signals that are randomly generated (`a` and `b` in your code). Those signals are *realizations* of *stochastic processes* (white Gaussian processes, in your case, because you use [`randn`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html)).

The *theoretical* correlation coefficient, on the other hand, is determined by the *statistical characterization* of the random processes that give rise to your generated signals of the two stochastic processes. So it's not obtained from simulations (as in your code), but computed mathematically.

The theoretical correlation in your case is 0, because the stochastic processes are *independent*. Note that I know this *from the code* (from *how* you generate the signals), not from  the actual values the code happens to generate. That's what I mean when I say it's a theoretical value: it's computed from knowledge that you have about how the actual signals are going to be generated.

The sample correlation can be used as and *estimation* of the theoretical correlation; and that estimation becomes *better as the signal size increases*. This is the [*law of large numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers). So, the larger you set the sample size (`1e6` in your code), the more concentrated the result (sample correlation coefficient) will be around `0` (theoretical correlation coefficient).

To illustrate this, I have done `10` sets of `1000` simulations, each set of a different sample size. For each sample size I thus collect `1000` different values of the sample correlation coefficient and compute a *histogram* to see how these values are distributed. The figure confirms that as sample size increases the histograms become narrower (and taller), indicating that the sample correlation coefficient is more concentrated around the theoretical value of 0.

[image]

---

The code used for generating the figure (Matlab R2015b) is:

```
S = 1e5:1e5:1e6; %// sample sizes
N = 1000; %// number of repetitions to generate histogram
binlimits = [-.015 .015]; %// set manually depending on S
B = 31; %// number of bins in the histogram
stretch = 7; %// stretch factor for plotting the histograms
result = NaN(numel(S),B); %// preallocate
for m = 1:numel(S)
    cc = NaN(1,S(m));
    for n = 1:N
        a = randn(1,S(m));
        b = randn(1,S(m));
        c = corrcoef(a,b);
        cc(n) = c(2,1); %// correlation coefficient
    end
    [hist, edges] = histcounts(cc,31,'BinLimits',binlimits,'Normalization','pdf');
    result(m,:) = hist; %// histogram of correlation coefficient for this sample size
end
bins = (edges(1:end-1) + edges(2:end))/2; %// axis for plotting the histograms
resultbar = NaN(numel(S)*stretch,B);
resultbar(1:stretch:end,:) = result; %// separate the histograms for better visualization
h = bar3(bins, resultbar.'); %'// plot histograms
set(gca,'xtick',1:stretch:numel(h),'xticklabels',S)
delete(h(mod(0:numel(h)-1,stretch)>0)) %// remove zeros
xlabel('Sample correlation coefficient')
ylabel('Sample size')
```

Comment: If I may explain it the other way around :

There will always be a non-zero probability that, non matter what sample size you take, your two samples will be perfecly correlated (Correlation coefficients would be 1 everywhere), even though this probability tends to zero when your sample size tends to infinity

Comment: thanks! So is the following way a proper way of calculating the theoretical correlation : mean(a*b')/var(a)*var(b) ?( formula is based on the formula for calculation of cross correlation coefficient between two signals ).

Comment: I have already increased my sample size form 1e6 to higher values but the cross correlation coefficient is different each time I run my code!

Comment: @anuribs it will always be different, but the differences should shrink as you increase your sample size, but they will never reach zero. Have a look at the exponents of your results, the larger you make your sample size the more negative your exponents should be getting.

Comment: You _cannot_ calculate a theoritical correlation from datas. the theoritical correlation between two random variables X and Y is defined as :

Cor(X,Y)=Cov(X,Y)/(SDx*SDy)

Where SDx (resp. SDy) is the standard deviation of the variable X (resp. Y).

Here, you can actually calculate the theoritical correlation, as your 2 variables are independant (as @Luis Mendo said in his answer), leading to Cov(X,Y)=0 , meaning that your theoritical correlation is 0.

Comment: 1) You would be calculating an _empirical_ 'insert term here', not a theoritical one (just remember that if you're calculating something from datas, you are never calculating something theoritical)

2) Correlation is not calculated that way, you have to use the correct formula : (see _sample correlation coefficient_)

Comment: very well explained @Luis Mendo & @ BillBokeey! Thank you :)

Comment: Just a small question: If i obtain correlation coefficient for complex signals as, say 0.18 + j0.2, should I take the absolute value of it or the real part of it in order to get the value of correlation coefficient?(I read that its always between -1 to 1, so I am wondering if it can be a complex number)

Comment: Good question. The coefficient can be complex indeed, and maximum similarity is achieved when it (is real and) equals `1`. But for other values of the coefficient I'm not sure if the real part or the modulus ir more meaningful. I usually take the modulus (absolute value)

Answer (score 2):

`randn` is programmed in such a way that it does not produce the same result per default every time you call it. If you want to generate the same set of random numbers for variables `a` and `b` every time you call your script you have to tell Matlab by setting the random generator accordingly. 
I wrote a small function `test` with the nested function `call_randn` to illustrate that. `test` calls the random generator 3 times and you'll see it generates the same `r` for all 3 calls. However, any time you call `test` these numbers will be different.

```
%// test
function r = test()
    rng('default')  %// Initialise random generator.
    sa = rng;       %// Store current generator settings in sa.
    rng('shuffle')  %// Get new generator settings.
    sb = rng;       %// Store new generator settings in sb.
    n = 10;         %// Number of random numbers to be generated.

    for i = 1:3
        [a(i,1:n),b(i,1:n)] = call_randn(sa,sb,n);
        R=corrcoef(a,b);
        r(i) = R(2,1);
    end
end

function [a,b] = call_randn(sa,sb,n)
    rng(sa);         %// Load generator settings.
    a = randn(1,n);
    rng(sb);         
    b = randn(1,n);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the seed of the random number generator or every time you call randn you will obtain a different distribution.
Check [randn](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html?searchHighlight=randn). In one of the examples, the random state is saved and every time it calls randn he previously sets the random state with the saved one, obtaining the same distribution:

```
s = rng;
r = randn(1,5)
r =
-0.0245   -1.9488    1.0205    0.8617    0.0012
rng(s);
r1 = randn(1,5)
r1 =
-0.0245   -1.9488    1.0205    0.8617    0.0012
```